# Remotely accessing Sharepoint 2013 using REST on Office 365 from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365

I want to integrate with SkyDrive Pro for file storage from a browser page directly, so I don't want to do this from our web server.

Almost every example I've seen of doing this involves either running code hosted inside Sharepoint itself or remotely over using C# in ASPX hosted on another site.

Can anyone point me to a pure JavaScript example that would run solely in an HTML page (NO server side code).

From what I can tell, this is possible, but nearly every authentication example uses C# libraries again. It doesn't look like they provide a client-side JavaScript library similar to the Windows Live SDK and it probably means constructing json/xml for the auth request.

Ideally, I want to simply popup the Office365 logon screen to authenticate and then be able to make API calls from my page using the browser session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be possible:

> Note that you cannot obtain an access token from code that is running
>   on a browser client. You must obtain the access token from code that
>   is running on a server and make it available to the client-side code
>   (by using a cookie, URL parameter, etc.).

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Your server side code needs to be in a sort of trust relationship with the identity server (Azure Access Control Services) in that they share a client ID and client secret (generated when your app is installed in Sharepoint as an app principal). See steps 6 and 7 of the process here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142382